# SP2010 workflow task-mails: invalid html in sended mails

Tags: workflow, xslt, tasks

Sometimes **(not always)** some task-mails are not displayed correctly.

**xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:nex="nowshare:xslt-extension">
    <xsl:template name="Form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$something"/>
                    </b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//Field[@ref='something']" disable-output-escaping="no" />
                </td>
            </tr>      
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It happens that html elements are (sometimes half) interpreted as text.

**result:**

> td>**My Value 1:**        my value 2

or:

> b>My Value 1:     my value 2

even though it should look like:

> **My Value 1:**       my value 2

The e-mail source code looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<table>
    <tr>
        td&gt;<b>My Value 1</b></td>
        <td>my value 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I could not yet figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. It works a lot better when accurate validated html code will be sent.
I have supplemented my code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><!-- --></head><body><!-- --></body></html>
```